# Regex to match both slash in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I want to match forward slash `/` or back slash `\` in particular string for e.g.:
1. `Hi/Hello/Bye/`
2. `Hi\Hello\Bye\`
3. `Hi\Hello/Bye\`
4. `HiHelloBye`
In the given strings only the last record should not be matched because it does not contain either `/` or `\`.

**What I am using**

```
if (strFile.matches(".*//.*"))
{
    //String Matches.
}
else
{
    //Does not match.
}
```

This matches for forward slash `/` only. I don't know how to write regex for both slash (for `OR` condition).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The "character" you're looking to match would be:

```
"[/\\\\]"
```

duplicating the backslash first for the string then again for the regex.

This is perhaps the nastiest bit of regexes when you need to use backslashes in languages that also use the backslash for escaping strings.

The Java compiler sees the string `"\\\\"` in the source code and actually turns that into `"\\"` (since it uses `\` as an escape character).

Then the regular expression sees that `"\\"` and, because it also uses `\` as an escape character, will treat it as a single `\` character.

> As Liu Yan points out in a comment, you could get rid of *one* level of backslashes (the regex one) by using one of the following:

```
".*[/\\x5c].*"
".*[/\\u005c].*"
```

> That might make it slightly more readable.

Once all that reduction is done, you have specified a character class consisting of both slashes and, if the character in question matches either of them, it returns true.

The following code shows this in action:

```
public class testprog {
    public static void checkString (String s) {
        boolean yes = s.matches(".*[/\\\\].*");
        System.out.println ("'" + s + "': " + yes);
    }

    public static void main (String s[]) {
        checkString ("Hi/Hello/Bye/");
        checkString ("Hi\\Hello\\Bye\\");
        checkString ("Hi\\Hello/Bye\\");
        checkString ("HiHelloBye");
    }
}
```

and it outputs:

```
    'Hi/Hello/Bye/': true
    'Hi\Hello\Bye\': true
    'Hi\Hello/Bye\': true
    'HiHelloBye': false
```

Comment: because the escaping occurs 2 times (one for java, one for regexp), it's seems hard to read, so sometimes I'll use `\x5C` or `\0134` to represent a single `\ ` character in regexp string. so the regexp becomes `.*[/\x5C].*`

Comment: Actually `[/\\x5c]` due to the string escaping, but I get your point. I'll add to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You want:

```
strFile.matches(".*[/\\\\].*")
```

Specifcally, replacing `//` with `[/\\\\]`.

You only need one forward slash, but you need 4 backslashes, because a single one is an escape within the string, and 2 is an escape for the regex, so you need 4.

Answer (score 2):

Use alternation:  `strFile.matches(".*(/|\\\\).*")` matches either a forward or backward slash.  You might want to take a look at the [Java regex documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: When I try `"abc/efg".matches("/|\\\\")`, it returns false

Comment: `matches` matches the _entire_ string, so the `.*` is very much needed. You might want to takes a look at the Java String documentation :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use this...

`[ ]` will provide you the **OR** functionality.

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("[/\\\\]");
Matcher m = pat.matcher("Hi/Hello/Bye/");

while (m.find()){

    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: `matches` matches the entire string, so the `.*` is very much needed like this `s.matches(".*[/\\\\].*")`

Comment: @KumarVivekMirta You are correct. I tried this using `Pattern` and `Matcher`. This works fine.

Comment: It takes lots of courage , to say that the other man is right... Keep it up... thats what makes a Man of Character..... cheers for u...