# forward slash - regular expression java

Tags: java, regex

For string x I want to match word abc between 
    https://  .... abc .../../..

- to determine if its of interest or not

Example

2) if string is https://  .... xyz .../abc/mnk  --> string is not of interest

3) or string is https://  .... xyz .../mnk/abc  --> string is not of interest

for forward slash matching

[Regex to match both slash in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789504/regex-to-match-both-slash-in-java)

http://bug-bounty.blogspot.com/2013/01/java-regex-forward-slash.html

To match forward slash I tried \ below partern and I tried

```
    a) x.matches("https://(.*)oem(.*)/(.*)"
    b) x.matches("https:\\/\\/(.*)oem(.*)\\/(.*)"
    c) x.matches("https://(.*)oem(.*)\/(.*)"  --> errors 
    d) x.matches("https://(.*)oem(.*)/(.*)/(.*)") --> works
```

Even thought d) works Both a) and b) fails for condition two - which means I havent understood things correctly . what am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

(The following items duplicate in part information from the sources you've linked)

- `matches` matches the entire string. Therefore d) works on your inputs while c) does not.
- you do not need to escape forward slashes. If you **do** escape characters in regexp pattern, however, you have to double each backslash you'd normally write - once for the string, once for the regex interpreter.
- Assuming that you want to match the substring of interest in the domain part of https urls, more robust regexen would account for this:

  `https://[^/]*oem[^/]*(/.*)?`

In case you know the (static) depth of the location part in your urls beforehand, you can safely apply pattern d) (reflecting precisely the known number of `/` in your urls).