# How to create regular expression with \ on the source

Tags: regex, jmeter

Help on how to create regular expression to extract data in JMeter.

Data to be extracted from:
`<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<ruleset id=\"8DEF7F30-165B-2C44-219E-DB7938283CD4\" locale=\"en\">\n\t<baseQuestions id=\"life\">`

I need a regular expression that can extract the ruleset id from eg above.

Here are the regular expressions that i tried to use:
`*ruleset id=\"(.+?)\"`
`*ruleset id=[^\\",]+`
`*"ruleset id"=\"(.+?)\"`

I tried other variations not I keep getting no match.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789504/regex-to-match-both-slash-in-java?rq=1

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape a backslash with another backslash:

```
ruleset id=\\"(.+?)\\"
```

[image]

References:

- [PCRE: Characters Escapes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Character-Escapes)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)